# SwiftAudio - Open filename which contains whitespaces

Tags: swift, url, whitespace

I'm using SwiftAudio library to open local url but I have a problem when I try to open an url that contains whitespaces in filename.

So, for example, if I try to open a file which name is "example_file.mp3" this audio is successfully opened.
But, if I try to open a file which name is "example file.mp3" an error occurs: "The requested URL was not found on this server". 
I've also tried to replace the name with "example%20file.mp3" but I have the same error.

I wrote this code:

```
var urlPath = "/Users/manuela/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/64E0D907-16AD-41A9-9667-4B3C701D4F1B/data/Containers/Data/Application/488A8AAD-EF4B-452D-9A8A-67307C489C72/Library/example file.mp3"
urlPath = urlPath.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!
print(urlPath)  // this prints "/Users/manuela/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/64E0D907-16AD-41A9-9667-4B3C701D4F1B/data/Containers/Data/Application/488A8AAD-EF4B-452D-9A8A-67307C489C72/Library/example%20file.mp3"
let url = URL(string: urlPath)!
let item = DefaultAudioItem(audioUrl: filePath, sourceType: .file)
let controller = AudioController()
try? controller.player.load(item: item, playWhenReady: true)
```

I'm sure that the problem is the whitespaces but I don't know with which character substitutes it. 
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Use `URL(fileURLWithPath:`, not `URL(string:`.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy for your response, I also tried to use URL(fileURLWithPath instead of URL(string: but the problem still remains. I think it's a library problem :(